# Can't find symbol when I try to create an object

Tags: java

When I try to javac my Persoon.java, it is going well but when I try to compile my Main it keeps saying this:

```
symbol:   class Persoon
location: package maandelijkseKosten
Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                Persoon tim = new Persoon();

symbol:   class Persoon
location: class Main
Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                Persoon tim = new Persoon();
```

I tried to find an answer online but without success, so I hope someone here can help me with this.
Here is my code:

```
package maandelijkseKosten;

public class Persoon {
    private String voorNaam = "";

    public Persoon() {
    }

    public Persoon(String voorNaam) {
        this.voorNaam = voorNaam;
    }

    public String getVoorNaam() {
        return voorNaam;
    }

    public void setVoorNaam(String voorNaam) {
        this.voorNaam = voorNaam;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package maandelijkseKosten;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Persoon tim = new Persoon();
    }
}
```

Comment: class `Persoon` should be in source file `Persoon.java` under directory `maandelijkseKosten` (same as `Main.java`)

Comment: As Sharon Be Asher said above, but also you need to compile from  maandelijkseKosten's parent directory with the command `javac maandelijkseKosten/Main.java`. Either that or set the classpath to the parent directory of maandelijkseKosten, e.g. using `javac -cp directory`

Comment: Please keep it english. You wouldn't want to read source code where every identifier was portugese, would you?

Answer (score 1):

As people say in the comments, you probably have incorrect directory structure. Here is how it should look:

```
> tree                                                                                                                                                   
.
└── maandelijkseKosten
    ├── Main.java
    └── Persoon.java

1 directory, 2 files
> javac maandelijkseKosten/Persoon.java                                                                                                                  
> javac maandelijkseKosten/Main.java                                                                                                                     
> tree                                                                                                                                                   
.
└── maandelijkseKosten
    ├── Main.class
    ├── Main.java
    ├── Persoon.class
    └── Persoon.java

1 directory, 4 files
> java maandelijkseKosten.Main
```